Manually set maximum value in scale_fill_viridis() when plotting rasters
I have some rasters of species ranges and I want to plot them in R. They overlap in some areas and I want the legend to show the number of overlapping species. However, I want the colour scale (and the legend) to refer to a higher number, because the legend will be in common among several maps and it should therefore reflect the map with the highest number of species.
This is my code so far:
set.seed(123)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(terra)
library(sf)

world <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sv")
# upload world vector as sf for plotting 
world_st <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")

# species range maps downloadable from here: https://www.iucnredlist.org/resources/spatial-data-download 
fish <- vect("../../Databases/IUCN/HAGFISH/HAGFISH.shp")
sp_list <- unique(fish$sci_name)

# create a list with species vectors 
mylist <- list()
i = 1

for(sp in sp_list){
  
  mylist[[i]] <- fish[fish$sci_name == sp,]
  i = i + 1
  
}

# create empty raster
r <- rast(extent = ext(world),
          crs = "EPSG:4326",
          resolution = 0.1)

# rasterize world
world_r <- terra::rasterize(world, r)

# rasterize ranges 
mylist_r <- list()

# rasterize a subset of species 
for(i in 1:40){
  
  mylist_r[[i]] <- terra::rasterize(mylist[[i]], r)
  # resample to world
  mylist_r[[i]] <- terra::resample(mylist_r[[i]], world_r, method = "near") 
  i = i + 1
  
}

# create a spatraster collection 
mylistsprc <- sprc(mylist_r)

# sum 
mylistsum <- mosaic(mylistsprc, fun = "sum")
print(paste0("Max number of species: ", minmax(mylistsum)[2]))
[1] "Max number of species: 3"

In this example, the maximum number of species I have is 3, but I want the legend to be based on a higher number of species (e.g., 4).
# create vector for plotting purposes (will be needed later)
maxsp <- c(1, 4)
# append to vector
maxsp <- c(maxsp, minmax(mylistsum)[2])

test <- mylistsum
test_spdf <- as(stack(test), "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
test_df <- as.data.frame(test_spdf)
colnames(test_df) <- c("value", "x", "y")
test_df$value <- as.factor(test_df$value) # this is needed if I want a discrete colour scale
df <- test_df

p1 <- ggplot() +
  
  # add world as a background
  geom_sf(data = world_st, fill = "grey90", col = "grey60", linewidth = 0.25)  +
  
  # add rasters
  geom_tile(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value), alpha = .75) +
  
  # add discrete viridis colour scale
  scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1, discrete = T) +
  
  # add theme map
  theme_map() +
    
    theme(legend.background = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "bottom", 
          legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
          legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"),
          legend.direction = "horizontal", 
          legend.text = element_text(size = 28),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 36),
          legend.title.align = 0.5)
  
  p1 <- p1 + guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", 
                                        nrow = 1))

  p1

This is how the maps looks like.

Now the problem is how to change the plot according to the maximum value (max(maxsp)) I want. I tried:
scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1, discrete = T, breaks = seq(1, max(maxsp), 1), limits = c(1, max(maxsp))) 

But the result is not what I am for:

I cannot understand how to manually change this value if not by manipulating scale_fill_viridis(), or if I am doing it wrongly.

Does it work if the factor for value is set with 4 levels and then you plot with scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE)

Not really: now it gets plotted with the four values but the maximum one (4, in this case) is shown in white. I get the same result with scale_fill_viridis(direction = -1, discrete = T, limits = c("1","2","3","4")).
